# ios swift how to change RTL to LTR view when change the language?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, app-store

Currently, I am working with localization on English and Arabic language. 
To change from RTL to LTR view I used exit(0) this will stop the app and user have to open it again. For that Apple reject my application while uploading to the app store.

I referred https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talabat-for-ipad/id477430407?mt=8 , it will chagne view without exit the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the trigger for changing the view? How can you do it from within your app?

Comment: what is the question ? the best is to check the language before loading the view. Or if the user changes, maybe display a popup saying that changes will be taken in account after restarting

Comment: If you can do it on initial load of the app, why can't you just update when the user changes it?

Answer (score 7):

You can change UIView's `semanticContentAttribute` with appearance proxy where you are calling exit(0) and setting the `rootViewController` of the window again.

```
func switchViewControllers(isArabic arabic : Bool){

        if arabic {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = arabic ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
            let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
            appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
         }
}
```